# Cannot destructure property 'executor' of 'audit.entries.first(...)' as it is undefined

Tags: discord, discord.js

Hi i write a code of audit log, and if i write logs of message delete i have error, how can i fix it?

error:

`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'executor' of 'audit.entries.first(...)' as it is undefined.`

code:

```
 client.on(Events.MessageDelete, async member => {

    member.guild.fetchAuditLogs({
        type: AuditLogEvent.MessageDelete,
    })
    .then(async audit => {
        const {executor} = audit.entries.first()
        
        const mes = message.content;

        if (!mes) return;

        const channelID = await db.get(`logchannel_${member.guild.id}`)
        const mChannel = member.guild.channels.cache.get(channelID)
        
        const logEmbed = new EmbedBuilder()
        .setTitle('Сообщение удалено')
        .addFields({name: "удалил", value: `${executor} **${executor.username}**  \n **ID:** ${executor.id}`, inline: false})
        .addFields({name: "канал с сообщением", value: `${message.channel}`, inline: false})
        .addFields({name: "сообщение", value: `${msg}`})
        .setTimestamp()
        .setColor('Blue')
        .setFooter({text: "log System"})
        if (channelID == null) return;
        mChannel.send({embeds:[logEmbed]})
    })
 })
```

Comment: Have you tried to log the value of `audit.entries`?